# Did Ubuntu provide support to Manchurian language?

Tags: fonts

I used to read some text on Wikipedia with some Manchurian text.  These texts scrambled on my Ubuntu computer, but are displayed fine on newer Windows platforms. Yesterday, I found that the text was displayed properly on my mobile phone, so I wonder if there is any setting I did wrong on my Ubuntu computer.

How shall I set to display vertical text like Manchurian language or Traditional Mongolian language correctly? Do I just need a proper font, or do I need to do some tweets?

Reference Text:

- https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B3%8C%E6%8B%9C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just need a proper font. Try to install the `fonts-noto-unhinted` package:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-unhinted
```

It installs the *Noto Sans Mongolian* font (and many other).

Comment: Thx! It does help! I think the Traditional Mongolian fonts coming with Ubuntu before did not have the rules set properly and thus did not rendered correctly. After installing this, the text are rendered correctly.